# How to log custom messages from inside a PostgreSQL transaction?

Tags: postgresql, log

I have a software that generates transactions and executes them. I would like to asynchronously inspect about the transaction progress in term of the simple proportion of queries executed over total number of queries. I'm able to read both `stdout` and `stderr` generated by `psql`, so I was thinking that a solution could be printing to `stdout` some custom messages like "Progress: 3/8" (or another custom text string).

I've thought about executing a "logging query" which stores in a proper table the informations about query progress, but this table wouldn't be available until the transaction completes, making it unuseful for me to inspect transaction progress.

At the moment I tried the following (suppose to have 3 queries in the transaction which do some stuff):

```
BEGIN;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION progress(curr int, total int) RETURNS float AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '___PROGRESS___%', curr/total::float;
  RETURN curr/total::float;
END;

-- First query
SELECT ... FROM ...;
-- Log the progress
SELECT * FROM progress(1,3);

-- Second query
SELECT ... FROM ...;
-- Log progress
SELECT * FROM progress(2,3);

-- Third query
SELECT ... FROM ...;
-- Log progress
SELECT * FROM progress(3,3);

COMMIT;
```

I execute the script from a bash file using the following syntax:

```
res=$((psql -U username -d db -h localhost --log-file=plog.log -f "the transaction above") 2>&1>clog.log)
```

What I get from a transaction like the one above using the previous bash command are three outputs: `plog.log`, `clog.log` and `$res` bash variable. I'll post some extract of them to make it clear what's their content.

### plog.log

```
....
********* QUERY **********
SELECT * from progress(1, 3);
**************************

     progress      
-------------------
 0.333333333333333
(1 row)

...
********* QUERY **********
SELECT * from progress(2, 3);
**************************

     progress      
-------------------
 0.6666666666666667
(1 row)

...
********* QUERY **********
SELECT * from progress(3, 3);
**************************

     progress      
-------------------
 1
(1 row)
```

### clog.log

```
...
     progress      
-------------------
 0.333333333333333
(1 row)

...
     progress      
-------------------
 0.6666666666666667
(1 row)

...
     progress      
-------------------
 1
(1 row)
```

### `$res` variabile (`psql` return value)

```
psql:/path/to/script.sql:11: NOTICE:  ___PROGRESS___0.333333333333333
psql:/path/to/script.sql:16: NOTICE:  ___PROGRESS___0.666666666666667
psql:/path/to/script.sql:21: NOTICE:  ___PROGRESS___1
```

The problem is that I can't real-time access the content of `$res` variable. I can instead access the content of `clog.log` and `plog.log`, so the usage of `RAISE NOTICE` doesn't make sense at all because it doesn't appear in both `clog.log` and `plog.log` but only in `$res`.

Should I stick to parse `clog.log` or `plog.log` in order to find the `SELECT` output value from the `progress()` function (removing the `RAISE NOTICE` statement in that function because of it's uselessness) or there's an alternative method? Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Try to redirect in the opposite order with `>clog.log 2>&1`. Then the notices should go to `clog.log`.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but in any way I redirect the ouput I'm able to parse and retrieve the output of my simple function yet. I was wondering if there was an alternative method for inspecting the real progress of any transaction in PostgreSQL

Comment: I've elaborated in an answer.

Comment: Thank you @DanielVérité! I'm evaluating also Aneesh answer because he gave a totally different solution.

Answer (score 6):

`RAISE NOTICE` is the right method.

The reason `RAISE NOTICE` output does not appear in `clog.log` is that your standard error redirection is wrong at the shell level.

You want:

```
psql --log-file=plog.log -f file.sql  >clog.log 2>&1
```

That way it redirects the standard output into `clog.log` and then the standard error to that standard output.

The way it's done in the question: `2>&1>clog.log` does not achieve that because of the wrong order, as described in the bash manual:

> Note that the order of redirections is significant. For example, the
>   command
>
> ls > dirlist 2>&1
>
> directs both standard output (file descriptor 1) and standard error
>   (file descriptor 2) to the file dirlist, while the command
>
> ls 2>&1 > dirlist
>
> directs only the standard output to file dirlist, because the standard
>   error was made a copy of the standard output before the standard
>   output was redirected to dirlist.

Comment: This is in an interesting contrast to what I saw while using `psql` interactively: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23618/6219

Comment: @dezso: indeed. To me, this is because `\o | program` does redirect psql's `stdout` to `|program` but does not redirect psql's `stderr` at all. Same behavior as the pipe in shell. Adding `2>&1` redirects the `stderr` of `program` to its `stdout`, but it's still independant of psql's `stderr`.

Answer (score 0):

In our system we use dblink's and write to the same DB. This is an alternative approach for Oracle Autonomous Transaction.

Here I use the concept of DB link to achieve the asynchronous commit for logging. This is as same as the concept of Autonomous Transaction in Oracle.
Commits done inside the db link will not cause a commit in the main transaction.

Actual data is written to log table via command "PERFORM PUBLIC.dblink_exec" and is committed immediately.

You can track the progress of your main procedure by querying the log table from a different session when the main procedure is still under execution, no matter if it errors out after hours of execution, log data remains committed.

```
#1: Confirm dblink extension

#2: Create DDLs
CREATE TABLE dblink_log (ID serial, message TEXT);--Table to store the logs

GRANT ALL ON TABLE core.dblink_log TO PUBLIC;--Permission to write as a dblink

GRANT ALL ON TABLE core.dblink_log_id_seq TO PUBLIC;

#3
/*Test block to write to a table and commit while 
  the main transaction is still in progress*/
DO$$ 
DECLARE
        open_connections TEXT [] := PUBLIC .dblink_get_connections () ; 
        --Cannot connect more than once before closing
        my_dblink_name TEXT := 'logging_dblink' ;
        --Define a name for your db link connection
    BEGIN

    --If the connection doest not exists, create one
    IF open_connections IS NULL 
       OR NOT open_connections @> ARRAY [ my_dblink_name ] THEN
        PERFORM PUBLIC .dblink_connect (
            my_dblink_name,
            'host=127.0.0.1  port=5432 dbname=dbname user=user password=password'
        ) ; 
        raise notice 'New db link connection made' ;
    ELSE
        raise notice 'Db link connection exists, re-using' ;
    END IF ; 

    FOR i IN 1..10 loop 

        PERFORM PUBLIC.dblink_exec (
                my_dblink_name,
                'BEGIN;
                 INSERT INTO core.dblink_log (message) 
                 VALUES (''Executing loop #' || i || ''') ;
                 COMMIT;'
            ) ; 

        perform pg_sleep(10) ;-- Execute select * from core.dblink_log
                              -- in a different session
    END loop ;
END $$;

#4: From a different session verify record core.dblink_log is populated with data
```

Comment: I'm curious about your solution and am looking for it :)

Comment: Okay, will get you some samples. But hope I got your requirement correctly.

Comment: I'm simply looking for a method to inspect the real progress of a given transaction in PostgreSQL. My idea was to explicitly "print" or "log" the progress as a call from inside the transaction as the number of completed queries over the total queries number, and then parsing the log from an asynchronous application (remember that a transaction locks tables and other stuff, except from some specific situations which aren't compatible with my case - see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-set-transaction.html ). Thank you for your support

Comment: Yes. I do the same via DB link. Will get you some code

Comment: @pietrop, I have updated my answer with a working example. Please take a look.

Comment: this is very interesting. You opened a backdoor in me about asynchronous capabilities of PostgreSQL! I clearly see the async-commit feature, but have some difficulties in understanding how your code interacts with the transaction. Does it happen in the `PERFORM PUBLIC ...` code? I've never used that statement :)

Comment: Try executing it in your system. What I gave you is a working version composed for you. You will just have to install dblink extension for PostgreSql

Comment: That array construction is unnecessary complicated, why not simply use a `ARRAY[my_dblink_name]`?

Comment: @dezso, I just corrected it. Thanks for pointing that.