# RAISE NOTICE doesn't work as expected while using within Dynamic SQL block

Tags: postgresql-9.6, dynamic-sql, aws-aurora

I have a small piece of code to get all sequences and the current and maximum value of all sequences in a database. I have tried `with recursive` and some other alternatives through plain sqls, however I couldn't find it. So I decided to use the dynamic sql as below:

```
do 
language plpgsql 
$$ 
declare qy text; 
        rs record; 
begin
    for qy in select 
    'select current_database(), iss.sequence_schema || ''.'' || ind.sequence_name,
    concat(''Cur'', ind.lvalue,'',Max:'',iss.maximum_value) from
    (select sequence_name, last_value lvalue from ' || quote_ident(sequence_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(sequence_name) || ') as ind,
    information_schema.sequences iss where iss.sequence_name = ind.sequence_name and iss.sequence_schema = ''' || sequence_schema || '''' from information_schema.sequences
    loop 
        execute qy into rs; 
        raise notice '%', rs; 
    end loop; 
end 
$$;
```

It works well in pgAdmin however, its not working in `psql` as expected. I do have two questions here:

1. Can I return the `res` values as result in dynamic sql? (I could if I do these operation via a function but I will not be having create / execute function privilege in the database since I will be using a guest user)
2. Why the `RAISE NOTICE` or `RAISE DEBUG` not showing anything in the console (using `psql`) even if I set the `client_min_messages` to `debug` or `notice`? I querying a rds instance. Is it something to deal with rds functionality?

Bottom of the line, I need to get all sequence's current value and max value along with schema name. It would be great if anyone shares an another way to achieve this without increasing the sequence value.

(I am using postgres 9.6)

Comment: You could attack the original problem in `psql` like `SELECT format($$SELECT * FROM %I $$, c.oid::regclass) FROM pg_class AS c WHERE relkind = 'S';` and then running `\gexec`.  As for the NOTICE, I don't know, it works as expected locally, and I am not in the position to set up an Aurora cluster to check this.

Comment: @dezso, I could do with help of your example like 
```SELECT format($$SELECT '%I' schemaname, '%I' sequencename, concat(last_value, ',', trim('%I','"')) 
FROM "%I"."%I" union $$, n.nspname, c.relname, s.maximum_value, n.nspname, c.relname) 
FROM pg_class c, information_schema.sequences s, pg_namespace n WHERE relkind = 'S' and s.sequence_name = c.relname
and n.oid = c.relnamespace and s.sequence_schema = n.nspname
```
I could save this as in plain ```.sql``` file and remove the ```union``` from last line and execute it. Is there any other feasible way I'm missing here?